# How to keep Task waiting on Remote Host in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am working on cluster set up for a software on windows server using Ansible and PowerShell script. The set up includes installation and configuration .

I am using Starfleet portal to run the job and we are storing comma separated hostnames in the Jinja file (InputHosts.j2). example hostname1,hostname2,hostname3. Hostnames can be 2 or more. As of now I am using only two hosts

I am storing hostnames in variable in ansible

```
vars:
 file_contents: "{{lookup('file', './files/InputHosts.j2')}}"
 central: "{{ file_contents.split(',')[0] }}"
 rim: "{{ file_contents.split(',')[1] }
```

1. First the installation should only happen on master node i.e. first hostname mentioned in the Jinja file
2. Once Step1 done then license should be applied only on master node
3. Once Step2 done then installation should only happen on remaining slave nodes in parallel
4. Once Step3 done then configuration needs to be done only on remaining slave nodes in parallel

I have a individual playbook created for each step mentioned above and each play book is calling powershell script.

I have defined roles for each step 1,2,3 and 4 and I am calling these roles in my master playbook as shown below . I am running master playbook on all servers mentioned in InputHosts.j2

```
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
   - vars/vault_vars.yml
   - vars/automation.yml

 roles:
    - { role: central, when: "ansible_nodename == central" }
    - { role: license, when: "ansible_nodename == central" }
    - { role: rim, when: ansible_nodename != central and ansible_nodename in file_contents }
    - { role: addrim, when: ansible_nodename != central and ansible_nodename in file_contents }
```

Problem:

I do not know how to put wait for installation on slave nodes until the license is enabled on master node as mentioned in Step3

Comment: I am running playbook using Starfleet portal

Comment: I have added all details